# Is it possible to prompt Google Bard to summarize a webpage's contents by giving it the link?

Tags: bard, summarization

As google Bard apparently has real time access to the Internet, I was trying to get it to summarize the contents a particular webpage, but it is absolutely refusing to do so no matter how I phrase the question.

For example, for this question

```
Summarize the content of the following website and tell me the product they are selling:

https://www.frye.com/wp/8000_hearing_aid_testing/
```

It came up with this:

> I couldn't find the website you linked. Is it possible you made a
> typo?
>
> I searched the web for "frye 8000 hearing aid testing" and found a few
> websites that sell hearing aids. However, none of them mentioned a
> specific product called the "frye 8000 hearing aid testing."
>
> If you can provide me with the correct website, I can try to summarize
> what they are selling.

And for a variation of the prompt

```
https://www.frye.com/wp/8000_hearing_aid_testing/

Summarize the content of the website given above and tell me the product they are selling
```

it gave this

> The website you linked is not working. I get a "404 Not Found" error
> message.
>
> The Frye company does sell hearing aids, but I couldn't find a product
> called the "frye 8000 hearing aid testing."
>
> If you can provide me with a working link to the website, I can try to
> summarize the content and tell you what product they are selling.

which is not correct as you can visit the site manually by directly clicking the link. I have tried few other variations as well but non are working. For a more popular website it does give somewhat of a correct response, but now I am not sure if it is actually parsing the hyperlink and retrieving the page's contents, or just detecting keywords in the link itself

```
https:\\www.google.com

Summarize the content of the website given above and tell me the product they are selling
```

gives

> I couldn't find any product being sold on the website you linked. The
> website is [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), which is the homepage of Google. Google is
> a search engine that allows users to find information on the internet.
> The website also offers a variety of other products and services, such
> as Gmail, Google Maps, and Google Drive.
>
> Is there anything else I can help you with?

```
https://example.com/
Summarize the content of the website given above and tell me the product they are selling
```

gives

> The website you linked is not selling any products. It is a
> placeholder domain name that is often used in documentation and
> examples. It is not possible to buy anything from this website.
>
> The domain name "example.com" is reserved by the Internet Assigned
> Numbers Authority (IANA) for use in illustrative examples in
> documents. This means that it can be used to show how a website should
> be formatted or how a particular feature should work. It is not a real
> website and does not have any content or functionality.
>
> If you are looking to buy a product, I recommend that you search for a
> website that is specifically dedicated to selling that product. You
> can find a variety of websites that sell products by searching on a
> search engine like Google.

For the webpage I was trying to summarize, I gave it the top level domain instead in a new chat tab:

```
https://www.frye.com/

Summarize the content of the website given above and tell me the product they are selling
```

This gives a longer result including formatting, bullets and images, a short part of which is shown here

```
The website you provided is for Frye, a company that sells high-quality, fashion-forward leather boots, shoes, sneakers, and bags for men and women. They have been in business since 1863 and are known for their classic styles and attention to detail.

On their website, you can find a wide variety of products, including:

Boots: Chelsea boots, chukka boots, engineer boots, hiking boots, moccasins, riding boots, snow boots, and more.
Shoes: Oxfords, loafers, sandals, sneakers, and more.
Bags: Backpacks, totes, satchels, wallets, and more.
```

It turns out the https://www.thefryecompany.com sells these products, but it has nothing to do with the webpage I was trying to summarize, other than the companies sharing similar name. The clothing company also probably has better SEO on google as the company whose webpage I was trying to summarize operates in a very niche market.

My questions are as follows:

1. How do I get Bard to summarize the contents of a website by providing a hyperlink? Can it even do this?
2. Is there a particular format I need to provide a hyperlink to Bard in, for it to detect it correctly as a website hyperlink?
3. What does it mean when they claim [Bard has access to the Internet](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bard/)? There is a "google it" link at the end of every response, but is it actually accessing information from the internet in real time to produce it's responses (as opposed to chatgpt whose knowledge cuts off at 2021)?

Comment: [Bard doesn't have access to urls](https://www.automatebard.com/2023/05/11/provide-post-about-how-to-use-bard-to-read-through-a-scientific-document-and-then-answer-questions/) apparently.

Comment: @AliasCartellano is this something they had before but removed recently? I am getting conflicting information when googling around and from other forums and blogs

Comment: It seems bing chat behaves the same way

Comment: Questions on this site should be specific. This means that there should be only one question per post.

Comment: @Wicket these are all related questions and each on their own post would be too trivial. There is no need to repeat all the background information on three posts just just to have a different question at the end. If this background information cannot be used to answer any particular questions above, then "this particular question X cannot be answered with the background information above" is itself an answer

Comment: “*As google Bard apparently has real time access to the Internet*” “*What does it mean when they claim Bard has access to the Internet?*” Please add some references for these claims, so that we can read them and check that there's no misunderstanding.

Comment: @A.L search google for [does google bard have internet access](https://www.google.com/search?q=does+google+bard+have+internet+access) and there are multiple results claiming it does. Although now that you mention it, I can't seem to find something official from google, even though I feel sure I have seen it before

Comment: Please **Edit** the question and quote the relevant parts of text. The article from XDA Developers may be wrong. In its current state, it looks like this question is built on a false premise that Bard can read URLs.

Answer (score 2):

I took a webpage with a basic page counter that increments for each new page load: https://github.com/antonkomarev

I used the prompt on https://bard.google.com/:

> `Summarize https://github.com/antonkomarev`

The basic page counter didn't increase. Therefore, Google Bard didn't try to fetch the URL's content in real time. (I don't think that counter is clever enough to filter out webcrawlers.)

However, I used the prompt:

> `Summarize https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/413/is-it-possible-to-prompt-google-bard-to-summarize-a-webpages-contents-by-giving`

and it summarized the page:

[image]

3 possibilities:

1. Some webpages are cached.
2. Bard extrapolates the content from the URL.
3. Bard  fetch the URL's content in real time for only some URLs, not all.

[automatebard.com](https://www.automatebard.com/2023/05/11/provide-post-about-how-to-use-bard-to-read-through-a-scientific-document-and-then-answer-questions/) that [Alias Cartellano](https://genai.stackexchange.com/users/145/alias-cartellano) found says it's possibility #2.

Comment: Do you have an idea why so many sources online say bard has access to internet or can summarize webpages or documents? Did google ever mention they did or were trying to implement such a feature? I have seem similar claims going around for bing chat as well, but from my testing bing chat behaves same as bard when it comes to summarizing web pages from links. Now im wondering what they mean by bard or bing having access to the internet. I hope its not just the 'search the internet' link that both of them give at the end of their replies

Comment: Although from your screenshot bard seems to have read the contents of the linked page, so thats even more confusing

Comment: @user13267 I also don't know. One experiment could be changing the webpage and see if the Bard output changes. Another experiment would be trying more URLs.

Comment: “*The basic page counter didn't increase.*” It may be due to the fact that Bard loaded the page but not the counter (displayed as a image). So the counter could have not seen the visit of the GitHub page. Like `curl https://github.com/antonkomarev` download the HTML but not the image, so you can get the content of the page while being invisible to the counter.

Comment: @A.L Thanks, great point. The next experiment is trying to change the text in the webpage then.

Answer (score 1):

Google Bard does appear to have access to the internet. When given the prompt "Present the current page of the news website theguardian" it accurately gave some of the articles that were present.

Having Bard get up to date content from websites is unreliable. It will sometimes provide out of date information or it may actually obtain the data from the website. It may be that to retrieve the data Bard needs a certain prompt that is catered for that website.

I tried to obtain the recent news on the website "climate.nasa.gov" and Bard managed to obtain some of the present articles.

I also checked other sites and it appears as though it can only attain present information on only some sites.

Getting Bard to use a url to enter a page doesn't work.